# Suppress warnings in specific user defined functions in R

Tags: r, append, warnings, suppress, write.table

I have a user-defined R function to write an output of my algorithm. To simplify everything, it looks like following:

```
writeMyOutput <- function (fileName="myOutput.txt"){
    fileConn <- file(fileName)
    method <- "BFGS"
    nIter <- "Num of Iter is 70"
    msg <- "Successful convergence"

    writeLines(c(method, nIter, msg), fileConn, sep = "\n")
    close(fileConn)
    estimates <- data.frame(matrix(rep(1:8), nrow =2, ncol=4))
    write.table(estimates, file=fileName, append=TRUE, row.names= F, quote = F) }
```

when I call this function, it gives me the following warning of write.table() append command,

```
enter Warning message:In write.table(estimates, file = fileName, append = TRUE, row.names = F,  :appending column names to filecode here
```

I wonder how I can suppress warnings for a specific user-defined function. If anyone can be of any help, appreciate that.

Comment: `suppressWarnings(expr)`

Comment: perhaps try `col.names=FALSE` in `write.table`?